# Adding data to the last row not empty of excel sheet c#

Tags: c#, excel, closedxml

Im trying to add data to the last row, and I googled and came up with code below but it does not work for me what is it that I'm doing wrong?

```
XLWorkbook wb = new XLWorkbook();
var ws = wb.Worksheets.Add(config.ReportName);
MapFilters(ws, excelReportSource.Filters);
ws.Cell(3, 1).InsertTable(dataTable);
long fullrow = ws.Rows().Count();
long lastRow = ws.Cells[fullrow, 1].get_End(ClosedXML.Excel.XlDirection.xlUp).Row;
```

The last row in my code I get syntax error on `ws.Cells[fullrow, 1]`, am I missing a namespace?

Comment: try lastRow = ws.usedRange().rows().count() + 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ws.Cells[fullrow, 1]` is the syntax for the EPPlus library, not ClosedXML. You're obviously mixing code meant for different libraries.